html - Navbar with border around

i am looking for create a navbar like the above but i am no idea how to make it. Can anyone help me
I already tried to let ai help but it's not get it Aboud concept of navbar. This is my current html code:
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="box">งานพัฒนานักศึกษา</div>
    <div class="box">งานบริการการศึกษา</div>
</div>

and css:
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    font-family: psuStidi-Bold;
    color: var(--primary-color);
    flex-direction: row;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

}
.navbar .box {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--primary-color);
    background-color: #b0b0b0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: none;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}
.navbar .box:active {
    background-color: #15325B;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
    border: var(--gray-color1) solid 1px;
}


"create a navbar like this" - like what?

There must be a billion navbar examples and tutorials online. AI doesn't know how to program...not sure why everyone seems to feel the need to mention that they consulted AI. It's no more useful than a beginner programmer anyway

If you have issues with your code, or tried to code something but the code isn't doing what you want, then ask. The code you gave works.

Sorry you all, i am newbie i forgot to upload image . Now i have uploaded. Thank for your help.

Welcome, adilan!  I edited your question to show the image inline (by prefacing the link with an exclamation mark; as well as a few other formatting tweaks).  Hopefully that'll help you get more helpful engagement with this question.  That said, you may wish to further edit it to more clearly say and/or show what exactly you're wanting to get, and what you're currently getting, and what's lacking about it.  Also, this probably doesn't directly help, but here's a CSS talk I liked that may help, and also points at some resources of general use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gT7H0qBdQq8

The first thing to do is reframe your understanding of what the visual effect you're looking for is. To a human it looks like the line is drawn "around" the nav tab, but here is what is happening in the eyes of a browser:

Both tabs have an extra container around them providing spacing between the edges of the tab and the line of the border
Nav1 has a border along the left, top, and right, with rounded corners on the top left and top right
Nav2 has a border along the bottom only

There are several issues with your code that will need to be addressed in order to achieve this.

First, the :active pseudoclass only applies to a elements, i.e. links, and it specifically targets a link that is being actively clicked on. In order to target the link correlating to the page the user is currently on you will have to add a real class to the nav item that corresponds with the current page.
Your navigation tab elements will each need to be enclosed in their own div to render the border around them, like so:

    <div class="navLinkContainer active">
      <a class="navLink">งานพัฒนานักศึกษา</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navLinkContainer">
      <a class="navLink">งานบริการการศึกษา</a>
    </div>

(Notice that I added a class to indicate the currently active tab).

Then we need to add padding to the container div so that it has the desired spacing between the nav tab and the border (exact pixel values can be adjusted):
.navLinkContainer {
  padding: 12px 0;
}

Then we can add the default border styles for inactive tabs - a single line along bottom
.navLinkContainer {
      border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
      border-style: solid;
    }

Then override them as necessary for the active tab
.navLinkContainer.active {
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}



Here is some reading on the CSS Box Model, it's a good starting place for understanding how to think about CSS problems.
